# jboss 4.2.2 worker thread initialization failure

Tags: java, jboss

im having jboss as server and java as client. there are some 200 client will access server daily.
this error coming every now and then on jboss log. any one tell me some idea.

```
ERROR [org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread] Worker thread initialization failure
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:237)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.peek(ObjectInputStream.java:2249)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readBlockHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:2429)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.refill(ObjectInputStream.java:2499)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:2571)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:820)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.readVersion(ServerThread.java:824)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.processInvocation(ServerThread.java:510)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.dorun(ServerThread.java:373)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:166)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a dropped connection between client and server. It'll happen every now and again with any network application, it's not much to worry about unless it happens a lot.

Comment: thanks. yes it happens a lot when server is busy. is there any way to reduce this and optimize the application.

Comment: ok.. sometimes server is too busy coz of lot of concurrent client actions. can u help me in setting "configuration" attribute in jboss-service.xml efficiently.so that i can optimize application. can u send proper configuration attribute properties tag for larger applications.